# Design Tree Structure With CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can i design following kind of structure with HTML/CSS ?
 [image]

Please provide Any reference sites links if you have

EDIT:
Sorry if you are not getting my question, its just that i don't know much about designing so
What i am trying to build is Tree structure but i don't know what HTML tags i should use and how will i draw these lines so just need your help for this. if you have any idea how accomplish this than please share.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to "draw" the actual tree picture with HTML?

Comment: By nodes you mean pages ?

Comment: @harsha That's not really helpful, you're basically saying "how about you write code that does it". (Which, okay, is technically a thing that has to be done, but still.)

Comment: @millimoose yes i am trying to draw a tree. and "node" is just static text.

Comment: @millimoose : I happen to know something which is exactly the same thing which OP wants but it's a jQuery Plugin.Hence the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart

This is a beautiful jQuery plugin which does exactly what you want.

Code Sample:

Let's say that this is your `unordered list`.

```
<ul id="org">
<li>
    Food
    <ul>
        <li id="beer">Beer</li>
        <li>Vegetables
            <ul>
                <li>Pumpkin</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Bread</li>
        <li class="collapsed">Chocolate
            <ul>
                <li>Topdeck</li>
                <li>Reese's Cups</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Add a dummy `div` like this

```
<div id="chart" class="orgChart"></div>
```

Now,you could simply use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#org").jOrgChart({
            chartElement : '#chart',
            dragAndDrop  : true
        });
    });
```

To render your `unordered list` into a directory tree/organisational chart structure.

Comment: @Hardik : The plugin uses `unordered list` to draw render the tree structure.

Comment: No link-only answers please. Perhaps you could provide a code sample or post your "answer" as a comment instead?

Comment: @JanDvorak : Sorry for providing the link only answer.Have added the code and retained the answer.Is this much code sufficient